# wait for file creation

Tags: silverlight, web-services, wait

i have a silverlight app which calls a webservice. that webservice encodes a wav file to mp3 format. how should be the best way to wait for full mp3 file creation?

regards

Answer (score 1):

Some kind of progress bar and message would be useful for your user. The progress bar doesn't necessarily need to show actual progress, it could just revolve indicating that work is being done.

However, if you wanted actual progress, you could have the web service generate the MP3 on a background thread, then return the service immediately to indicate generation had started. Then the Silverlight client could make a request for progress repeatedly until the service indicated the generation was done and provided the file. That way you could actually provide a progress bar that edged towards 100%.